# Significance of number 1239 in The Santa Clause

Tags: analysis, the-santa-clause

Here's a festive one for all you guys and girls!

During *The Santa Clause*, Scott and Charlie eventually land at the north pole and are greeted by an elf.

[image]

They watch as the elf raises 'the North Pole' from the ground, and a keypad flips out of the side.

A close up then reveals, quite deliberately, the elf typing the code **1239** into the keypad, which activates the elevator, lowering the sleigh into Santa's secret hideout.

### What is the significance of these numbers?

It's unlikely they would use such a lingering shot without purpose, but the numbers don't appear to have any significance to the rest of the film, as far as I'm aware...

Is this a Christmas reference of some kind? or is there some other significance to these numbers in connection with Santa that I'm unaware of?

Are there any of Santa's little helpers out there that know?

Comment: Random guess: It should have been a dumb and easy to remember password, yet it should be semi-secure, so they started off with "123" and ended with the highest number available.

Comment: December 25, 1939 - 12/39 - the introduction of Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer. See: http://www.historyorb.com/date/1939/december People sometimes use birthdays as PINs or passwords.

Comment: @wbogacz, put it as an answer! If it's correct I can't mark it as so in the comments...

Comment: @wbogacz I'm curious to know how you came by this answer/guess. (Well done!)

Comment: @coleopterist you have been asked to cease rollingback by a Mod, please respect my decision, and allow me control over my own question.

Comment: I haven't seen anything by any mod. This site is like a wiki. The concept of you "owning your question" does not exist. We like logic and reason here and unless I can be convinced that the tag is required in your question's title or that my edited title is not reflective of your question, I have no qualms about correcting your error. Furthermore, the fact that you quite gracelessly started rolling back the changes of other users sans comment only vindicates my stance. In any event, as I stated long ago, take this to meta.

Comment: Perhaps you missed Iandotkelly's comments when he closed to question temporarily to stop your rollback war, which you have once again begun. There is an absolute precedent for authorial control on this site, it is implicit in every question. You have every right to disagree, but I have every right to defend myself: The voting will decide if my title gains the attention required. Please stop, this is entirely unneccesary, and I have made no 'error', it's just a personal preference that I prefer my own wording of the question. That's all.

Comment: This is transparently harrassment. Your behaviour has been flagged to a Mod, (again). Hopefully this time you will respect their judgement. Please stop.

Comment: @coleopterist - I will give you the benefit of the doubt that you didn't see the comment. As stated in the meta - I don't see why you cannot keep a movie name in the title if the title remains short.  A rollback war over a silly thing like this is ridiculous and simply unacceptable.

Comment: It is true however that on SE there is no such thing as 'the author has the right to approve all changes' hence the scope which allows for such content disputes. However clearly the author of a post has some natural sway over the content in cases where its not a matter of strict policy.  In a matter of such triviality, where there is no clear cut policy, where the title is not degraded in any way by the inclusion of the movie name I would recommend just dropping this.

Comment: 'clearly the author of a post has some natural sway over the content'... this is exactly what I mean about ownership being *implicit*, you have worded it better than I.

Answer (score 12):

Long shot here... Maybe the authors were interested in the idea of a code for underground worlds...

Subway lines 1239 take you through NYC to Penn Station/ 34th Street (think *Miracle on 34th Street* - that other movie about whether Santa is real, which is referenced in the *Santa Clause* at one point when the children scream "Let him go! Let Santa go!").

[image]
[image]

These numbers have also been referenced elsewhere in pop culture (the Springfield subway is actually abandoned but still functional):
[image]

Credit to [John Rizzuto](http://fineartamerica.com/products/subway-1239-john-rizzuto-art-print.html) for MTA photo and [Fox](http://www.thesimpsons.com/) for the the Simpsons photo. Subway line 9 was a skip-stop line that ran from 1989-2005, so current photos of subway stops and maps only show 123 instead of 1239.

Comment: This is very interesting, and very well researched! If these aren't to be taken as co-incidence, it seems as though there *is* some kind of pre-established connection between these numbers that the movie is pointing to. I wonder what it is?

Comment: I looked for connections between the writers (Leo Benvenuti and Steve Rudnik) and the Simpsons, but so far have turned up nothing... Was hoping that by posting this much, someone else might be able to help establish such a connection. Until then, it's entertaining speculation!

Answer (score 2):

The current Walt Disney Studios, located at 500 South Buena Vista Street, Burbank, was made possible by the revenue from the 1937 release of Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs. Walt Disney and his staff began the move from the old studio at Hyperion Avenue in Silver Lake on December 24, 1939. So 1239 (Dec '39) is when Disney moved to their permanent location.

Answer (score 0):

Disney uses 1239 a lot in their movies and things just like "we have a 2319" or the north pole code and D23 because 1923 was the year walt started the company.

Comment: Do you have a source for this that you could [edit] in to back up your answer? This is quite terse at the moment.

Comment: I always thought "23-19" was intended to refer to the 23rd and 19th letters of the alphabet -> "W-S" -> "white sock" (the object the alert is about).

Answer (score -3):

KJV Translation Count — Total: 5x

The KJV translates Strong's G1239 in the following manner: distribute (2x), make distribution (1x), divide (1x), give (1x).

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost. Can you [edit] to explain further? What is a KJV translation? How does this relate to the question??